# Regex in Pymongo

Tags: regex, mongodb, python-2.7

I have been reading the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/#dbcmd.text) on mongodb, and I am trying to write a function to run a full text search, but I want to search for regex. In the document they say that "blue" will not return "blueberry." Is there a way to get around this?

EDIT: I am trying to search every field for a regex. I realize this is "expensive" from a resource standpoint. I will be using indexes

Here is my search function (that works, but not for regex):

```
def search(db, col, search_text):
    if( not search_text ):
        return "";
    print db.name, col.name, search_text
    query = db.command("text", str(col.name), search={search_text})
    results =[]
    for result in query['results']:
        results.append(result['obj'])
    return results
```

If I try:

```
query = db.command("text", str(col.name), search={"$regex":search_text})
```

I get:

```
OperationFailure: command SON([('text', 'test'), ('search', {'$regex': u'\\bnet\\b'})]) failed: no search specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my searching, I cannot find a way to do this. This is the best I could come up with:

```
def search(db, col, search_text):
    if(not search_text ):
        return "";
    else:
        search_text = str(search_text)
    query = col.find({})
    results = []
    for result in query:
        if(str(result.values()).find(search_text)>=0):
            results.append(result)
```